# Android Retrofit2 POST call not triggering HTTP request

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit2 /RxJava on Android. My POST call works fine in general. But now I added the call from another location. When invoked, there is no HTTP post request sent, no errors/exceptions. HttpInterceptor isn't seeing the call either. Its hard for me to find out what I am doing wrong in this instance.

```
mAccountManager.onAuthChange()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(authCode -> {
            if (mAccountManager.isLoggedIn(authCode)) {
                someOtherApi.getIds()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe(idList -> {
                            mUserApi.doSomething(idList);
                        }); 
            }   
        }); 

...

@POST("/api/users/dosomething")
Observable<Void> doSomething(@Body IdList idList);
```

I made sure retrofit api is called by putting breakpoint.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Make sure that it's going inside `if (mAccountManager.isLoggedIn(authCode))` condition. Also add the onError part for the `mAccountManager.onAuthChange()` to see if it's giving any error

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: your onAuthChange is getting called indeed, but what I asked is to check once it reaches the `subscribe` part that if your condition is getting fulfilled or not

Comment: ok got it, `mUserApi.doSomething(idList)` returns observable & it won't fire until you subscribe to it. so you must subscribe to `mUserApi.doSomething(idList)` as well then only it will fire

Comment: @SandipSoni thank you - that was the problem. Please add as answer and I will mark as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrofit's rx-adapter creates **cold** observable, i.e it won't do anything until you subscribe to it. so the problem for you is, you are not subscribing to `mUserApi.doSomething(idList);` API call.

so just subscribe to it & it'll get called. Also I am not sure about the code of `mAccountManager.onAuthChange()`, but you should have the onError part as well inside the `subscribe` to avoid `UndeliverableException`